# ajax jQuery asp.net error Unexpected token <

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, jquery

I am having trouble adding ajax functionality to existing asp.net 4 website.
I have both tried creating webmethod in the aspx page and also tried asmx, but in both cases I get this error `Unexpected token <`

this is my jQuery:

function postAssets(datapm) {

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            timeout: 20000,
            tryCount: 0,
            retryLimit: 10,
            url: "talk.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log('success postAssets '+msg.d);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                if (status == 'success' || status == 'notmodified') {

                    console.log('complete postAssets' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {

                console.log('error postAssets');
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is what is in asmx:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for talk
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class talk : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public talk () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

I wonder if I am missing any webconfig items, or is it all built in in asp.net 4?

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings />
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <machineKey validationKey="BA5B68AB87AAEA30753960733E796568" decryptionKey="FAF15E4015737A7695D9761" validation="SHA1" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you returning JSON or markup? Your call to jQuery's `ajax()` method is expecting JSON but if you're returning markup that starts with a `<` character then I could imagine it throwing that exception.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you declare your Ajax type as `POST` while in your ASP Controller you declare `HelloWorld()` as WebMethods. That's why your ajax can't find your HelloWorld Function.

Try to delete this line:

```
[WebMethods]
```

and see if that works.