# How to force datatype as JSON in ASP.Net 2.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I got the following working after spinning my head around a thousand times and then referring [parserrror SyntaxError: Unexpected token < - Load Partial View using jQuery Ajax in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882705/parserrror-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-load-partial-view-using-jquery-ajax)

I have the following code in my `ASP.Net 2.0` project. It works – but to get it to work, I am using `dataType: "html"`. When I use JSON as datatype I get a parse error: `Unexpected token <`

How can we make it work with `JSON`?

Note: Though I am using IE8, some of my users are still using IE6. So I need a solution that works in **IE6**.

**jQuery Ajax**

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "admPlantParametersViewEdit.aspx/GetResult",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(msg) 
            {
                alert("Hi");
            },
            error: errorFunction
        });
```

**VB.Net**

```
   <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GetResult() As String

        Return "hello"

    End Function
```

**Request and Response Headers**

[image]

**References**

1. [Differences between contentType and dataType in jQuery ajax function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322984/differences-bettween-contenttype-and-datatype-in-jquery-ajax-function)
2. [What is content-type and datatype in an AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701282/what-is-content-type-and-datatype-in-an-ajax-request)
3. [How to return JSON from a 2.0 asmx web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288850/how-to-return-json-from-a-2-0-asmx-web-service)
4. [ASP.NET AJAX PageMethods call load whole page for .NET 4.5 IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720337/asp-net-ajax-pagemethods-call-load-whole-page-for-net-4-5-iis-7-5)
5. [Support cross-domain requests (specifically multiple methods in WebInvoke) in Rest WCF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c412e600-0f4e-4a5b-8c45-bf77ed04f2a8/support-crossdomain-requests-specifically-multiple-methods-in-webinvoke-in-rest-wcf#e9e1a5a7-9a76-41a0-ab4f-fd6ad76b18aa)
6. [jQuery $.ajax(), $.post sending "OPTIONS" as REQUEST_METHOD in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099787/jquery-ajax-post-sending-options-as-request-method-in-firefox)
7. [Cannot set content-type to 'application/json' in jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754767/cannot-set-content-type-to-application-json-in-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Your vb.net code doesn't return a JSON type. Have you tried to set the `contentType:text/plain;`

Comment: I did not click through all your references, however have you checked out [JsonConvert.SerializeObject](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after referring following two posts

[encosia  - ASP.NET web services mistake: manual JSON serialization](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20Encosia%20%28Encosia%29)

[encosia - ASMX ScriptService mistake: Installation and configuration](http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistakes-installation-and-configuration/)

> Since you’re using .NET 2.0, the most likely culprit is that you’ve got the AJAX Extensions installed, but haven’t updated your web.config to use that new handler for ASMX requests.

**STEPS TO SOLVE:**

1. Download ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 and install it, if not done already
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=883
2. Add proper httpHandler after removing the existing one as shown below  [This configuration is for **.Net 2.0** only. Refer the blog mentioned above for other versions]

   ```
      <httpHandlers>

       <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>

       <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" 
            type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory,
            System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0,
                        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

   </httpHandlers>
   ```
3. Refer [jquery ajax with asp.net not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750339/jquery-ajax-with-asp-net-not-working)

As

```
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </httpModules>
```

and

```
      <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>           
        </assemblies>
```

.4. Made it as `POST` and `json`

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admPlantParametersViewEdit.aspx/GetResult",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) 
            {
                alert(msg.d);
                alert(msg);
            },
            error: errorFunction
        });
```

---

This answer won’t be complete without quoting the following lines from encosia

> The ability for ASMX services to return raw JSON is made possible by two key features originally added by the ASP.NET AJAX Extensions v1.0
>
> 1. JavaScriptSerializer
> 2. ScriptHandlerFactory

**Good Reads**

1. [Scott Gu's  - JSON Hijacking and How ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 Avoids these Attacks](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks)
2. [A breaking change between versions of ASP.NET AJAX](http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/)
3. [ajax jQuery asp.net error Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075862/ajax-jquery-asp-net-error-unexpected-token)
4. [ASMX ScriptService mistake: Installation and configuration](http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistakes-installation-and-configuration/)
5. [Using JSON.NET with ASP.NET Web API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx)
6. [jQuery, ASP.NET Web API, and Json.NET walk into a bar…](http://encosia.com/jquery-asp-net-web-api-and-json-net-walk-into-a-bar/)
7. [Deployment problems with ASP.NET AJAX applications](http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2007/10/26/deployment-problems-with-asp-net-ajax-applications.aspx)

Comment: Also read [Hanselman - Deserializing JSON with Json.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek4DeserializingJSONWithJsonNET.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

in request you need to set Accept: application/json ,the if you server has json support then it will send response in json automatically,

```
        type: "GET",
        url: "admPlantParametersViewEdit.aspx/GetResult",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        Accept: application/json,
```

then in response header you should see

```
        content-type:application/json
```

not 
            content-type:text/html